# Show a loading message while php is processing followed by a redirect to another page

Tags: php

I am trying to write a page in php which shows a loading message while it does some processing and then auto redirects to another page

```
<?php
    //show a loading message - this is the bit I need help with
    // do some processing - don't need help with this bit
    header("Location: http://www.mysite.com/mynextpage.php");
    exit;
?>
```

I can't use echo or javascript otherwise I get a "Cannot modify header information - headers already sent" error when the page executes.

Any clues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using java script to redirect after the processing has finished seems to be the way to go.

I'm using

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.location="http://www.mysite.com/mynextpage.php";
</script>
```

at the end of the page and it's working

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you mustn't use any header change after outputing some data, that is why you get the error above.
Another way, use header redirections by refreshing page on next page:

```
<?php
    header('Refresh: 5; url=http://www.mysite.com/mynextpage.php' ); 
    echo 'Wait 5 sec then redirected';
```

Note:

> Remember that **header()** must be called before any actual output is sent, either by normal HTML tags, blank lines in a file, or from PHP. It is a very common error to read code with include, or require, functions, or another file access function, and have spaces or empty lines that are output before **header()** is called. The same problem exists when using a single PHP/HTML file.

Comment: He wants to redirect just after some calculation, he can't specify seconds

Comment: For your solution, the output will be done after things are done so, this is not a "Loading". It's just some "I'm done!" message - during the work, the page is still loading.

Answer (score 0):

Best way is to use ajax requests. Via javascript you should show the loading element, perform the request, on success redirect on target page

Comment: He doesn't need help for that as he said but yes ajaxould be the solution